# Motherboard won't POST with Xeon Phi installed

Tags: memory, motherboard, pci-express, xeon

I've got an [ASUS P9X79 WS motherboard](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/P9X79_WS/) with an Intel Xeon E5-1650 v2 processor that I'm trying to install a Xeon Phi 3100A on. A colleague of mine had this setup working about a year ago, but we had to modify the configuration for some other testing. Now we're trying to get this back up and running, but we're drawing a blank.

Specifically, as soon as we plug the Xeon Phi into one of the PCI x16 slots, any attempt to boot leads to a Q-Code of 19 and the DIAG_DRAM LED lighting up. I've tried a variety of solutions, including:

- Trying the Xeon Phi in the second PCI x16 slot (according to the manual, the two x16 slots operate at that speed solo or at x8 if both are in use) (no dice)
- Testing a graphics card in both slots (worked fine)
- Testing a second Xeon Phi we have (still nothing)
- Triple-checking the power connections (at first I used separate rails for the 8-pin and the 6-pin connectors, but on reviewing our PSU's specs I realized it shouldn't matter if we only used a single rail. Neither configuration works, however.)
- <strike>Slamming my head against the machine in frustration</strike>
- Swapping in and out a variety of RAM sticks (all of which work if the Xeon Phi is *not* plugged in)

Are there any steps I'm missing? I'm confused as to why the DIAG_DRAM LED would light up anyway -- there's nothing to indicate that the RAM is problematic. It has to be with the Xeon Phi at this point, right?

Comment: Does your coprocessor have a fan? If not, how are you cooling it? It will not work without some cooling system. Have you upgraded your BIOS to the latest for your motherboard? Have you enabled "[above 4G decoding](http://kmpic.asus.com/images/2013/12/09/65f08878-18b3-4b79-9fc0-c92255609c63.jpg)" in your BIOS (it may be called "Xeon Phi support")?

Comment: the manual says q-code 19 is "memory init started," and the manual further states that for incompatible memory it will light the LED. There apparently is a "MemOK!" switch you can then press and it will go through a series of "memory tuning" algorithms which can time and re-boots between tests I think. Have you attempted this process? Perhaps the card has on-board memory that is exposed, or perhaps the system thinks it is a video card.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Yes, I've upgraded the BIOS to the most recent version (twice). And I have enabled "above 4G decoding". As for cooling - it's the "A" series, so it comes with a fan built in.

Comment: @Yorik: I've tried the "MemOK!" switch numerous times to no avail - doesn't seem to matter what RAM sticks I use. The video card angle isn't one I've thought of, but if it's true, I'm not sure how to diagnose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer turned out to be that the Xeon processor in question, E5-1650 v2, is NOT supported by the Xeon Phi motherboard.